# Grabbing the current web api request from external code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to write code that will grab a file from the current request from a web api action and then save the file to the server.  This code is in it's own project separate from the main web api project. When the code runs I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

This is the code in it's own project that should capture the request:

```
public class Upload<T> where T : HttpRequestMessage
{
    private readonly T _req;
    // Constructor
    public Upload()
    {

    }

    public Upload(T t)
    {
        _req = t;
    }

// METHODS
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SingleFile(string dirName, string typeDir)
    {
        // check request

        if (!_req.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            return _req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        // More code etc.
    }
}
```

This is the calling code from within the main web api project:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateProduct()
    {
        var up = new FileTools.Upload<HttpRequestMessage>(this.Request);
        var message = up.SingleFile("test", "mytestDir"); // error appears here

        return message.Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your project that contains your upload class is referencing a different version of System.Web.Http than your web application.  Check your references to make sure they are referencing the same assembly.

Comment: You were correct. The properties tab revealed that the Runtime Versions appeared to be the same but that the Version number at the very bottom of the properties tab were different.  I ended up having to import the web api 2.2 nuget package into the the separate project to get the version numbers to match.